# How to use winsock in C++ to pass $_get superglobal to a .php on localhost

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I am trying to use a c++ script to pass some informations from this script to a local server (localhost) using a socket connection.

As I would like to interact with a DB and I am more comfortable with php, I would like to pass the data through $_GET superglobal sending the complete URL correctly and directly formatted with the $_GET[''] variables (not so much hack issues as I am on a stand alone machine).

I read many posts about using winsock2 for cpp, and I step by step implemented the examples in my cpp program but I am experiencing two troubles:

1) I put in the host structure the localhost through gethostbyname() function. I would like to be sure the ip adress is the correct one, but a printf of a converted-into-char host->h_addr sent me back something not looking like an ip_adress. Do you have any better way to see what host got by this function? Is it safe to use gethostbyname() on localhost?

2) I would like to know how I can correctly write the data to be sent to the server to perform the action on the database as would do the opening of the dedicated php web page. I am interested by the correct result, but would me much more interested by a complete and correct reference (website would be nice, or even book) to know what is the correct syntax for message send to the server on a socket.

Hereafter is my code:

```
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("localhost");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Could not connect");
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected!\n\n");
    }


    char url[100] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost/CoffeeTime/remove.php?scard_ID=";
    strcat(url, scardid);
    strcat(url, "&remove=1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    int url_len = strlen(url);
    printf((char*)url);
    printf("\n");

    send(Socket, url, url_len, 0);
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
```

As you could see, nothing new under the sun, I took most of this code from someone on stackoverflow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facing the huge number of answers :) , I will try to give the best answer I could as I finally succeeded to reach my server through this connection.

The solution is only in the string sent to the server : as I use a XAMPP server I could easily see through Netstat that the connection is OK (gethostbyname works well with "localhost" in arg so no need to use inet_addr with a static localhost ip for people as noob as I am.

Looking at XAMPP apache server log and after opening the adressed php page I've seen at the end of the file the GET string and it is no need to give the /localhost/ before the complete link. Moreover, the GET string ends with HTTP 1.1 instead of starting with it.

Finally, my correct syntax is

```
    char url[100] = "GET /CoffeeTime/remove.php?scard_ID=";
    strcat(url, scardid);
    strcat(url, "&remove=1\r\n74AD45C8&remove=1 HTTP/1.1 \r\n Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

So no big deal, no huge announcement but it can be interesting for people who use XAMPP to see more useful stuff going with the XAMPP control panel.

Thanks to the guy who downgrade me with no comment by the way :o) .